# QR code detection having large data using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Hello guyz I am working on a project in which I need to detect QR code in a image and decode its data. Currently i am using open cv and its working on QR codes with leser amount of data and not on QR code which are generated using hash as data. QR code examples:

Lesser Data QR code:
[image: Image having "hello" as QR data]

QR code having hash as data:
[image]

My code is detecting small data QR codes perfectly but not similar on large data QR 
Small data = "hello"
large data = "62f67621b020cbb6897ad7e7ba1d54581aa9f1571189e40f8f5c34aa5489b6e4"

Detection code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = data_uri_to_cv2_img(values['image'])  #function used to convert Base64 data to image

detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
data, bbox, straight_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(img)

def data_uri_to_cv2_img(uri):
    encoded_data = uri.split(',')[1]
    nparr = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(encoded_data), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the library `pyzbar` would be better for you. I tested it and it worked for both pictures.

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import cv2

pyzbar.decode(cv2.imread('largeqr.jpg'))
```

```
[Decoded(data=b'hello', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=1442, top=641, width=357, 
    height=356), polygon=[Point(x=1442, y=641), Point(x=1442, y=997), Point(x=1799, 
    y=997), Point(x=1797, y=641)])]
```

As you can see it also gives the coordinates of the 4 corners of the QR code.